# QtAbstractItemModel. Using QtreeView and QtableView together

Tags: qt, treeview, tableview, qabstractitemmodel

My application is a tool library manager.  It has a treeview containing a list of lists and tools.  It also has a tableview showing a list of tools.

When I click on a list in the treeview, I want to show the tableview with the list of children.  When I click on a single tool in the tree, I switch widgets and display the editform for the tool.

How do I limit the tableview to only the children of the selected node in the treeview?

My data model is a custom qAbstractItemModel.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a complete answer to my own question but I'm much closer.  On the tableview I can call setRootIndex() and pass in the current item from the qTreeView.  This works to show only the children of the current tree item in the table list.

For me, it still shows both tools and child lists, which I want to filter, but I think that's a different issue.

Comment: Please put your comments under the answer, instead of creating a separate answer. Thx.

Comment: My comment was not about another answer.  It was a new answer not yet discussed.

Comment: Got it. What's your strategy for mapping and showing in table view only the children under the selected item in tree view?

Comment: downvoted because no example to show how to proceeed.

Answer (score 0):

I have a *similar* situation (not quite the same!) as yours. Before I share my experience, my assumption is that you have a database of sorts which consists of the items that make up your lists/tools.

One possible solution is to create two custom models, one for the tree view (say, `MyTreeViewModel -> QAbstractItemModel`, associated with `QTreeView`) and one for the table view (`MyTableViewModel -> QAbstractItemModel`, associated with `QTableView`).

The two custom models should be fed by the *same agent working with the database*. The *key difference* is that the tree view model works with the entire database, and the table view model with only a subset, that is, the children of the chosen item in the main list. Think of it as full mapping v. partial mapping of the database.

When the user clicks on the top list of nodes in the tree view, you can emit a signal which could be picked up by `MyTableViewModel`, populates with only the children, and is displayed by `QTableView`.

Because the same agent serves both models, you should be able to maintain data integrity, in the sense changes to the underlying data by one model should be reflected in the other model. This solution has worked out really well for my application. Hope this works for you too!

Comment: @sliptonic The different views (table, tree, etc.) are all a **type** of view. In your case you have mapped *all the data* to two different views. There is *no way the view can filter the data*. My solution fixes the issue by creating a model that  filters the data - then `QTableView` shows the reduced data. QT's Model/View/Delegate architecture allows us to do that. If my solution is not correct, either my understanding of your problem is incorrect, or the right question has not been posed.

Comment: If you find out that there is an easier way to filter the data presented in a view compared to creating a separate model , please post it here. Thanks.